# Can resoure qualifier adapte tablet and phone

Tags: android, android-layout

In the past，I  used  -xlarge  to  adapte  tablet , but It didn't work when I use below-8.0-inch tablet(very odd,google developer file said It will work when talbet 's size above 7 inch ), know I used small width,  Can I determind wheather is  tablet  according   smallwidth  like this?

tablet -------------  sw481dp

And I want to ask what's the minimum size of tablet's smallwidth? what's the maximun size  of  phone's  smallwidth?

Comment: There is none.  Tablet vs phone is a meaningless distinction-  the difference between them is whether they have a cellular radio (and even then some tablets have one of those).  There isn't a magic size where one is a tablet and one is a phone, its a marketing term.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)

> Almost every app should provide alternative resources to support specific device configurations. For instance, you should include alternative drawable resources for different screen densities and alternative string resources for different languages. At runtime, Android detects the current device configuration and loads the appropriate resources for your app.

And as it's mentioned in the doc , it works for phone and tablet , the only matter is the dpi : pixel density

So if you want to know what is the smallest density for phone and tablet it will be hard to answer cause every phone and tablet has its specific dpi but what i can say let the os decide from which property it has to choose the icon